# using User ID feature, export to bigquery

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

I have a question when using the User ID feature to track users across devices/browsers.

If I activate the transfer service from GA to Bigquery in which field will I get that information. Would it use the same fullVisitorId column or a new one will be created?

thanks,
mike

Comment: Once in big Query, can it be exported out? I am still confused if it's possible to get events associated with a userID out of Firebase Analytics or GA.

Answer (score 1):

The field is called `userId`.

More info can be found [here](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/3437719?hl=en). Please note that for this data to appear in BigQuery, you must make sure to select the User ID view when setting up the GA/BigQuery link.

Answer (score 0):

The GUID will be new field and can be found as a custom dimension.